# Display Select Name Data issue in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to select one name in a name list then displays details of that particular person and again select another person in a name list then deselect previous one and show the details about new selected one.I did but it shows data to all members without selection also.I didn't get any idea about this.So please see the below code and suggest me what to do?

Html Code:

```
<td><div class="cdata">
    <div class="user {{selected}}">{{Firstname}} {{Lastname}}</div>
        {{#if selected_name}}
                      {{selected_name}}

         {{else}}

            {{/if}}
  </div></td>
```

JS Code :

```
//TODO :: Show Contact Details of User

  Template.userlist.selected_name = function ()
  {
  console.log("Session.get"+Session.get("selected_player"));
    //var player = Players.findOne(Session.get("selected_player"));

    return "hi";//Here sample to show selected one as 'hi' message
  };

 Template.userlist.selected = function () 
  {
   console.log("Session.equals"+Session.equals("selected_player", this._id));
    return Session.equals("selected_player", this._id) ? "selected" : '';
  };

//TODO :: Events
 Template.userlist.events
  ({
    'click .user': function ()
    {
     console.log("You pressed the user name"+this._id);
      Session.set("selected_player", this._id);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saying `{{#if selected_name}}`, you are saying "if any name is selected". This is because the helper returns a string for the currently selected name, regardless of the current template context's name. You need to change it to:

```
{{#if selected}}
  {{selected_name}}
{{/if}}
```

This works because empty strings in JavaScript are falsy values.